# netkit: Connecting 3 routers and trying to ping router 3 to router 1

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

hey guys,
I am using Netkit to simulate a network, I am using the static routing lab provided by Netkit and I am trying to set up 3 routers.
I have 3 routers each with a pc connected.

pc1 on r1 can ping pc2 on r2 and vice versa.

pc3 on r3 can pnig pc2 on r2 and vice versa.

***but pc1 cant ping pc3 on r3.***

This is my problem I can't seem to get a connection between pc1 on router 1 to connect to pc3 on router 3.

Below is how I have configured the network:

**r1.startup:**

ifconfig eth0 195.11.14.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 195.11.14.255 up

ifconfig eth1 100.0.0.9 netmask 255.255.255.252 broadcast 100.0.0.11 up

route add -net 200.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 100.0.0.10 dev eth1

**r2.startup:**

ifconfig eth0 200.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 200.1.1.255 up

ifconfig eth1 100.0.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.252 broadcast 100.0.0.11 up

ifconfig eth2 100.1.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.252 broadcast 100.1.1.11 up

route add -net 195.11.14.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 100.0.0.9 dev eth1

route add -net 195.20.14.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 100.1.1.9 dev eth2

**r3.startup:**

ifconfig eth0 195.20.14.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 195.20.14.255 up

ifconfig eth1 100.1.1.9 netmask 255.255.255.252 broadcast 100.1.1.11 up

route add -net 200.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 100.1.1.10 dev eth1

**pc1.startup**

ifconfig eth0 195.11.14.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 195.11.14.255 up

route add default gw 195.11.14.1 dev eth0

**pc2.startup**

ifconfig eth0 200.1.1.7 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 200.1.1.255 up

route add default gw 200.1.1.1 dev eth0

**pc3.startup**

ifconfig eth0 195.20.14.9 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 195.20.1.255 up

route add default gw 195.20.14.1 dev eth0

**lab.conf:**

r1[0]="A"
r1[1]="B"

r2[0]="C"
r2[1]="B"
r2[2]="D"

r3[0]="E"
r3[1]="D"

pc1[0]="A"
pc2[0]="C"
pc3[0]="E"

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it could be more interesting to post it in serverfault ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the routing table of R1, It needs another `route add` to the network `100.1.1.0/30`.

(BTW, my netkit tutorials (sadly in french) are [here](http://kartoch.msi.unilim.fr/wiki/index.php?n=Netkit.HomePage) and support for wireshark between machines is [here](http://kartoch.msi.unilim.fr/blog/?p=19))

**update**: please check your routing tables: each router need to know the destination network to be able to send packets to it. For instance, how R1 can understand to which router it has to send if It don't know the destination network 195.20.14.0/24

Comment: Hey thanks but when i try route add -net 100.1.1.0/30 gw 100.1.1.10 it does not work :( .